# mkfifo with all permissions still errors with permissions denied for other user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, fifo

Ubunbu 20.04

fifo pipe is created via a bash script from user `A` with: `[[ ! -p $fifopath ]] && mkfifo $fifopath -m0777`

This creates: `prwxrwxrwx 1 A A 0 May 25 00:40 /tmp/somefifo`

Then, if user `B` attempts to write to the fifo, permission will be denied. If i change the group of the fifo to user `B`'s group, permission will still be denied. Only if i change the owner to be `B` or `root`, then `B` can write to the fifo.

Problem manifested after an update from 18.04

Any ideas how to solve this thing?

Answer (score 1):

[This patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5) (maybe introduced in Ubuntu 19.10?):

> Disallows open of FIFOs or regular files not owned by the user in world
> writable sticky directories, unless the owner is the same as that of the
> directory or the file is opened without the O_CREAT flag.

I took these steps to disable it as [detailed here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1875225#yui_3_10_3_1_1628122552213_162):

> create `/etc/sysctl.d/protect-links.conf` with the contents:
>
> ```
> fs.protected_fifos = 0
> ```
>
> Then restart procps:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl restart procps.service
> ```